# How to design a table for the following requirement?

Tags: mysql

I have the following requirement.

Parent child mapping table

> ID      ParentID     ChildID
>
> 1          1            2
>
> 2          1            3
>
> 3          2            4
>
> 3          2            5
>
> 3          4           6

Main Table

```
ID  ViewCount

1   3  
2   4    
3   4 
4   5   
5   6
```

The Parent and childs are present in the same table itself and having their own viewcounts.

Whne I read any record it has to get the particular records viewcount as well as their child's view count.

I have updated only the particular records viewcount, not updated their parents.

So from the main table, When I access the record with ID 1, it has to get all of their childs viewcount and its own viewcount. for this case 22.

when i access 2 the viewcount is 15.There is no level into that, it will grow in accordance with childs.

How to write a query or redesign the table or anything

to implement the above requirement?

The ID column present in the main table refers both Parent and child ID's and its the primary key also. In the mapping table we are mapping the parent & child relationship. ID present in the parent/child table is table's primary key field.Right there is no use of that field

Comment: In your "Main Table", what's the ID? Is it the ID from the other table, or ParentID/ChildID? My *impression* is the latter, but...

Comment: ...and what is the "ID" in the parent/child table? I thought at first it was a unique ID for a specific parent/child relationship, but you have three 3s.

Comment: can a child have more than one parent? Is the ID in the main table referring to the id in the parent/child table? I assume the three 3s is a typo, and should be 3 4 5?

Comment: The ID column present in the main table refers both Parent and child ID's and its the primary key also.

In the mapping table we are mapping the parent & child relationship.

ID present in the parent/child table is table's primary key field.Right there is no use of that field.

Answer (score 4):

The structure you have (parent/child) is called Adjacency List.  Getting a node and all its children (for example to sum their `ViewCount`s requires recursion.  Don't hold your breath waiting for MySQL to implement it: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=16244.  The SQL standard feature, CTEs, is implemented with almost identical syntax by most major SQL databases (PostgreSQL, DB2, MS SQL Server, possibly recent Oracle); Oracle has a CONNECT BY / PRIOR.

There are other encodings of trees that can be queried without recursion, but they're somewhat more complicated than Adjacency List.  Google "sql nested intervals", or read [Vadim Tropashko](http://vadimtropashko.wordpress.com/2008/08/09/one-more-nested-intervals-vs-adjacency-list-comparison/)'s book

Oh and BTW, that synthetic id column in your parent/child table is terrible design since it allows you to have duplicate data.  Drop it, and create primary key over the two columns that really belong there.

Answer (score 0):

In your program do you have any objects that represent the parent and child items? If so you can do the recursion in the program to get a list of Item IDs then you can do the following.

SELECT sum(ViewCount) FROM MainTable WHERE id in (*List from program*)

Comment: I don't have any objects to hold the parent,child items.